# Link to a different page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following code which should go to a particular company page from the request page. In the website folder Company page is under a folder called Companies and the request page is under Requests folder.

```
 Dim strUrl As String = "/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" & .Company_id
 litlCompany.Text = "<a href=" & strUrl & ">" & .Company.Name & "</a>"
```

The Url should be built as,

http://localhost/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=222

But it comes as,

http://localhost/Requests/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=222

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: If you use ~ in front of your URLs it will go to the root folder then you can access the folders beneath. This is very handy in masterpages. So for your example it would look like `Dim strUrl As String = "~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" & .Company_id`

Comment: http://localhost/Requests/~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=254. It comes like this now.

Comment: Using a Literal for the purpose of a HyperLink is the long way around keeping things tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

```
Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" + Company_id)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are currently on `http://localhost/Requests/something.aspx`? If so, that's because you forgot the tilde root specifier:

```
~/Companies/Details.aspx
```

Which should fix your problem.

Comment: Will this still work given the way he's doing things? Won't the tilde just get written to the href in his literal?

Comment: Possibly. If he wants to ensure the URL written to the link tag is correct, he would be better server simply making `strUrl` the combination of `Request.Url.Host` + `strUrl`

Answer (score 1):

By the name of your control it appears that you are using a `Literal`.

Try changing this to a `HyperLink`, then you won't need to put the HTML (`<a href=...`) in the text property, you will be able to use `hypCompany.NavigateUrl = strUrl` and ASP.Net will generate it for you. This is the neatest way to do it anyhow.

Also add in the tilde to go to the root :-)

E.G.

```
Dim strUrl As String = "~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" & .Company_id
hypCompany.NavigateUrl = strUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that this link is built in the request.aspx page.

I think the a href is being rendered to the current httpcontext. Have you tried creating the string as :

Dim strUrl As String = "~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" & .Company_id

I think this will work if the Companies folder is in the root. The tilda should ensure it looks from the root down.

Comment: Yes. The link is built in request.aspx page. I ve tried the  Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Companies/Details.aspx?Company_ID=" + Company_id). Its working now